# NoClassDefFoundError when running from the comand line

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath

I would like to use an external library (e.g. Google's Guava) for my Java program. I use Eclipse, so I downloaded Guava's jar (and source) and followed [Adding a Java library to the project classpath](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath_jar) to add it to Eclipse and to the buildpath of my project.

This works fine: I can run the program from Eclipse and from the runnable jar I export from Eclipse, but I get an error when I try to run directly from the `bin/` dir, as I used to do before:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Joiner

What should I do?

Comment: show us the command you used before.  chances are you aren't adding the jar to your classpath.

Comment: If you update your question with more information, it will get bumped to the top of the Active page where it will get more views.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the class file directly from the project bin directory then you may have to specify the classpath manually:
`C:> java -classpath C:\java\MyClasses;C:\java\OtherClasses MyClassHere`

Comment: I can't get it to work, now it can't even find my main class. Where exactly should I point the class path? Is the root of all classes ok? The bin of each package?

Comment: You point the classpath at the guava library. You go into your bin directory as usual and run with the same command, just adding the `-classpath C:\libs\guava.jar` to it

Comment: actually, this doe snot work for me. From the bin/, I can run java myPackage.myClass but once I add -classpath with the external jar myPackage.myClass is not found. I also tried adding myPackage.myClass path to the cp (separated by ';') but this didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Youll have to tell Java where to find the library:

```
java -cp <path-to-lib-jar>;myJar.jar my.package.MyMainClass
```

or if you wanna use a jar file you can set the library path in the MANIFEST
check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)#Setting_the_path_in_a_Manifest_file) for an explanation.

Comment: You can't use -classpath (or -cp) with the -jar option. It will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

To run the program on console as precise as possible with when you run it from Eclipse, you need to run it from the root directory of the project (not from bin) and don't forget to mention the classpath (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html)

So for example on root you will run:

> java -classpath lib/guava.jar;bin packageName.className

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `java -cp guava.jar ...` ?